# 0 Value instead of NULL in column MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, geocode

I have a script that geocodes physical addresses and puts it into a MySQL database with two columns: `coord_lat` and `coord_long`. These are `float` type columns but unfortunately some addresses don't get geocoded correctly and the script tries to push the address as a **`null` value** into the database which then breaks the script because the database cannot hold a `null` value.

I'm trying to find a way I can rewrite my script to determine if the geocoded address comes out to a `null` value to automatically rewrite that value to `0` so that the database and script don't break.

Can anyone give me some advice on switching/replacing a `null` values to `0`?

Comment: Can you show the code where the default value of `null` is being input?  At face value it sounds like you should default those two values to `0` and then overwrite them with the correct value after creating the geocode values.

Comment: 0,0 is a real place on the earth. Maybe you want to use 91,0.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

if PHP (shorthand if)

```
(is_null($value) ? 0:$value)
```

else if MySQL (coalesce function)

```
SELECT COALESCE(@your_value_here,0) FROM dual
```

for reference of coalesce:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html

for shorthand if statement (ternary):http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples

Comment: ...or in php, `$value=(integer)$value`

Answer (score 1):

If the value is NULL, then assign 0

```
if(is_null($value)){
  $value = 0;
}
```